# Rasterio: tool for creating mosaic?

Tags: rasterio, image-mosaic

Is there in Rasterio any way to create a mosaic?

I tried to google it, but I couldn't find anything, maybe someone else already used it.

I want to use some open source possibilities, I already know of possibility to use gdalmerge, gdalwarp.

Comment: That would be `merge` from the `rasterio.merge` module, or `rio merge` from the command line.

Comment: Thank you. I like the vision of using CLI however I found only 'rio-merge-rgba', is there possibility that 'rio-merge' is over?

Comment: It's `rio merge` without the dash. `rio --help` will give you the list of all CLIs, and `rio merge --help` will give you more specific help for that command in particular.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are really helping me. Do you maybe know something about resampling, please? In rio-merge-rgba I read it doesn't work with bilinear and there is forced nearest neigbour.

Comment: If you need to resample then I suggest you use `gdalwarp` instead. It does mosaicking, reprojecting/resampling all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rasterio's `rio warp` command (see https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/rio/warp.py) can be used to make image mosaics. With a little work you could use that function in Python code, not just as a command line program.

Answer (score 13):

```py
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from rasterio.merge import merge
from rasterio.plot import show

src1 = rasterio.open('/path/to/your/raster1')
src2 = rasterio.open('/path/to/your/raster2')

# Taking a peek to make sure these are the rasters you want...
show(src1)
show(src2)

srcs_to_mosaic = [src1, src2]

# The merge function returns a single array and the affine transform info
arr, out_trans = merge(srcs_to_mosaic)

show(arr) # Check to make sure the merge looks good.
```

I was just looking for a similar technique and found this method based on the rasterio/merge.py function given [here.](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/522cf4d7f45b9bf3a1d9ca2f42e6b9f417cd4e8e/rasterio/merge.py)

You can check out my example with two orthomosaic images [here.](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/charparr/jupyter-notebooks/blob/master/Rasterio%20Merge.ipynb)

However, I'm not sure this is the best method...no doubt the dude himself @sgillies has more insight into this!

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, I was repeatedly receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    mosaic, output = merge(raster_to_mosaic)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I had been importing merge as:

```
from rasterio.merge import merge
```

For some reason, as soon as I changed my package import call to the following, it worked without issue:

```
from rasterio import merge

mosaic, ouput = merge.merge(raster_to_mosaic)
```

*p.s I would've commented this but alas I am but a low-level contributor*

I hope this saves someone the hour it took me to work-around!