# Merging rasters with gdal_merge.py

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, merge, gdalwarp

I'm trying to create a mosaic raster from two rasters. With `rasterio` works well but `gdal_merge.py` subprocess calling doesn`t work for me.

My Error is:

> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import subprocess, glob
from osgeo import gdal

files_to_mosaic = glob.glob('C:/Users/DanielKovacs/Documents/GranCanaria/mosaic_L2A_T28RDS_A025431_20200505T115222_2020- 05-05_con/*_B04.tif')
files_to_mosaic

files_string = " ".join(files_to_mosaic)
print(files_string)

command = "gdal_merge.py -o mosaic2.tif -of gtiff " + files_string
output = subprocess.run(command)
output
```

Comment: subprocess cannot find gdal_merge.py, you have to specify full path to gdal_merge.py or use os.system which inherits the path from the os. You can erase imports for numpy and matplotlib and gdal.

Comment: The same happens `command = "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/gdal_merge.py -o TEAK_Aspect_Mosaic.tif -of gtiff " + files_string
output = subprocess.run(command)
output`

Comment: `command = "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/gdal_merge.py -o C:/Users/DanielKovacs/Documents/GranCanaria/mosaic_L2A_T28RDS_A025431_20200505T115222_2020-05-05_con/output.tif -of gtiff " + files_string
output = os.system(command)
output` With this statement gives me no error, however the output file is not created in my output path.

Comment: Is there any other alternative using `gdal`?

Comment: Why not just `python gdal_merge.py -o out.tif in1.tif in2.tif` as in the example https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html? Did you know that for most use cases (IMHO)  gdalbuildvrt https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html#gdalbuildvrt is a better option than gdal_merge?

Comment: Your're right! gdalbuildvrt is just amazing and fast. I had executed from OSGeo4W Shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably do this with `gdal.Warp` in Python directly:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

files_to_mosaic = ["a.tif", "b.tif"] # However many you want.
g = gdal.Warp("output.tif", files_to_mosaic, format="GTiff",
              options=["COMPRESS=LZW", "TILED=YES"]) # if you want
g = None # Close file and flush to disk
```

There's [loads](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html) of other options you can add on to this.

Comment: Very usefull, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've used @Jose answer but I had issues with `nodata` (apparently, an option for telling `gdal.Warp` what values to ignore is necessary), I had the black of superior images covering the one below.

Using `rasterio` though worked nice (from this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/247430/88415):

```py
import rasterio
from rasterio.merge import merge

with rasterio.open(files_tif[0]) as src:
    meta = src.meta.copy()

# The merge function returns a single array and the affine transform info
arr, out_trans = merge(files_tif)

meta.update({
    "driver": "GTiff",
    "height": arr.shape[1],
    "width": arr.shape[2],
    "transform": out_trans
})

# Write the mosaic raster to disk
with rasterio.open(output, "w", **meta) as dest:
    dest.write(arr)
```

Where `output = 'mosaic2.tif'` and `files_tif` is the list of input tif files.

Comment: `gdal.Warp` has options `srcNodata` and `dstNodata` to e.g. translate all input missing values into (e.g.) a single output "no data" value.